# How to determine if a AWS Lambda function exists

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am new to AWS SDK for JavaScript. I need to check if a Lambda function exists before I trigger execute on it.

I tried the following:
Each time I make a `lambda.getFunctionConfiguration()` using Function name I have to execute. If it returns an Error, the function doesn't exist. If I get meta, I continue with execution.

I feel this is not a cleaner way to handle this. Is there any other way to check if Lambda exists with the name?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't a sensible exception also be thrown if you simply try to trigger it without checking anything?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot tried it. Doesn't feel like a clean approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ListFunctions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#listFunctions-property) JavaScript API and check if the `lambda` function is in the output.

```
listFunctions(params = {}, callback) ⇒ AWS.Request
```

> Returns a list of your Lambda functions. For each function, the
>   response includes the function configuration information. You must use
>   GetFunction to retrieve the code for your function.

Corresponding CLI: [aws lambda list-functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/list-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to check if function exists with [`listFunctions()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#listFunctions-property) SDK method (*proposed by helloV*) in more `async` way.

```js
const {Lambda} = require('aws-sdk');
const lambda = new Lambda({apiVersion: '2015-03-31'});

const lambdaExists = async (fName, marker = null) => {
    try {
        const {Functions, NextMarker} = await lambda
            .listFunctions({
                Marker: marker || '',
                MaxItems: 50
            })
            .promise();

        const exists = Functions.map(({FunctionName}) => FunctionName).indexOf(fName) !== -1;

        return exists || NextMarker;
    } catch (e) {
        // Handle with care
        console.log(e.toString());
        return e;
    }
};
```

Function returns `true` if function name is found in current iteration or `NextMarker` (*string*) if not. Iterations end when there is no `NextMarker` provided in received response.

> **Note:** This function is a generic representation of possible way of solving the issue. Not fully tested in real conditions and could need some corrections to be used in your code.